# How to check two md5 encrypt value is same or not using php?

Tags: php, md5

I have two md5 value

Both string value is same but generate different md5.

So, how to match both value is same? Because in Hash function i am using Hash::check function for this type of problem.

Comment: I think it's impossible to generate different md5.

Answer (score 1):

If the two strings generate different md5 values, they are different strings. Perhaps one has a slightly different character encoding, a different comma character, or something of that sort. But comparing the equality of the two hashes, is the same as comparing the equality of the base strings -- that's the whole point of md5 :)

Comment: yes thats encoding, i had the same problem, because of using another md5 algorithms. And my string included special chars in my language.